# Create a 2D array and initialize every element to be the value of i * j where i and j are the 2 indices (for instance, element [5][3] is 5 * 3 = 15)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, initialization

I am truly stuck here on how to do this. I got as far as creating the 10x10 array and making variables i and j - not far at all. I thought about the use of loops to initialize every element, but I just don't know how to go about doing it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

public class arrays {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] array = new int[10][10];
    int i = 0, j = 0;   
}
```

}

I was thinking of using a do while loop or for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psuedo-code:

```
for i = 0 to 9
   for j = 0 to 9
       array[i][j] = i*j
```

Converting this to Java should be a snap.

Answer (score 1):

Create two nested `for` loops, one for `i`, and one for `j`, looping over all valid indices.  In the body of the inner `for` loop, assign the computed product to the 2D array element.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two for loops inside each other:

```
int[][] array = new int[10][10];
for (int x = 0; x < array.length; ++x)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < array[y].length; ++y)
   {
       int product = x * y;
       // put the value at the right place
   }
}
```

You can read this as:

> For each x value, iterate over the ten y values and do...

Answer (score 0):

```
 int [][] array = new int[10][10];
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
             //initialize every element
             array[i][j] = i + j; 
           }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works - just need to change + to * in array[i][j] = i + j.

Comment: If you could add some explanation of this answer, it would make it even more helpful for future visitors (and more likely to get upvoted).